# 'File not found' while importing gif for Tkinter.Label

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to import gif into a Tkinter.Label. I'm getting a file does not exist error. I have double checked the path and file name.

Below is the error message I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sachin\Desktop\Project California.py", line 39, in <module>
if __name__=='__main__': main()
File "C:\Users\sachin\Desktop\Project California.py", line 35, in main
feedback = Feedback(root)
File "C:\Users\sachin\Desktop\Project California.py", line 11, in __init__
self.logo = PhotoImage(file= "‪C:\\Users\\sachin\\Desktop\\signature.gif")
File "C:\Users\sachin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36                                    
\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3542, in __init__
Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "‪C:\Users\sachin\Desktop\signature.gif": no 
such file or directory
```

Here is the code I used.

```
def __init__(self,master):

    self.frame_header = ttk.Frame(master)
    self.logo = PhotoImage(file= "‪C:\\Users\\sachin\\Desktop\\signature.gif")
    ttk.Label(self.frame_header, image = self.logo)
```

I'm a noob in python programming. Apologies if the questions is too trivial.

Comment: If python is telling you the file doesn't exist, it's usually telling the truth. What happens if you go to command prompt and type `dir c:\Users\sachin\Desktop\signature.gif`?

Comment: It asks for a prompt to choose the app to open the file. Trust me, I copied the file path from it's properties. I'm wondering if I have incorrectly installed python or something with System vars!

Comment: If you had installed something incorrectly you would be getting a different error. Did you try doing what I suggested in my first comment?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error and I'm sure the path is right as well. In fact, it seems to find the file every other time it tries, with very similar code.

`for r in range(0,5):
        for c in range(1,4):
            fn = file_name(c)

            try:

                photo = tk.PhotoImage(fn)
                tk.Button(C, image = photo, width = "16", height = "16").grid(row = r,column = c)
            except Exception as exception:`